# ¿Como reemplazar etiquetas con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero reemplazar unas etiquetas específicas mediante el uso de JavaScript.

La etiquetas que quiero reemplazar son estas `<!--` y `-->`. Entre estas dos etiquetas tengo código que se ejecutará cuando cargue por completo la página.

Este es mi código:

```
function listen(){
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
[].slice.call(html).forEach(function(el, i){
el.innerHTML.replace('<!--', '<script>').replace('-->', '</script>');
});
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
listen();
}, false);
```

Comment: Ya explicaste cómo querías que se comportara, pero faltó explicar cómo se está comportando ahora. Por otro lado, ¿Quieres reemplazar todas las ocurrencias en el documento, o una sola? ¿Quieres que se ejecuten los scripts así "insertados"?

Comment: El problema es que no se ejecuta y no hace lo que debe hacer.

Comment: El código no se va a ejecutar simplemente reemplazando los tags. Tienes que usar `document.createElement('script');` La respuesta de @GustavoGarcia hace todo lo que necesitas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extrae el contenido del script entre `<!-- -->` usando expresiones regulares, luego, creas un elemento `script` y lo añades al final del body para su ejecución.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let scriptText = "<!-- alert('Hola'); -->";
let matches = scriptText.match(/<!--(.*?)-->/);
let code = matches[1].trim();

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = code;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Sin embargo, no le veo ningún sentido a lo que haces, **a no ser que realices algún proceso** cuando cargue la página y luego añadas los scripts. Simplemente no hagas eso; si quieres cargar scripts **al final del parseo y carga del DOM** utiliza el atributo `defer` en los scripts, como lo indica @Lorthas.

Comment: Tu ejemplo, me serbio de mucho. :) Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Replace crea una nueva cadena con el texto remplazado, no modifica la cadena actual.

Por tanto deberías hacer:

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('<!--', '<script>').replace('-->', '</script>');
```

Referencia: [String.prototype.replace en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

creo que por temas de legibilidad deberías tener los scripts en un fichero a parte del html y más si los quieres cargar a posteriori.

Si lo quieres cargar a posteriori es tan fácil como que los cargues añadiendolos al html. Te dejo una pequeña función que hace esto:

```
function loadScript(url)
{
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = url;
}
```

Solo tienes que pasarle la ruta/nombre del fichero y ya lo tendrás disponible.

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es cargar simplemente ciertos scripts después de haber cargado el DOM (cosa que he entendido yo al menos) lee lo siguiente:

Según https://m.genbetadev.com/javascript/javascript-defer-vs-async
Si añades el atributo defer a la etiqueta script, el codigo Javascript no se ejecutará hasta haber cargado todos los elementos de la página.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="url/archivo.js">
  </head>
  <body>
  <body>
<html>
```

También puedes para asegurarte poner la etiqueta script antes de cerrar el body.
Async y Defer son de HTML5.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar (editando) cómo tu respuesta se relaciona con el pedido del OP?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Esque lo que quiere, es cargar scripts después de haber cargado el DOM, o eso parece por su codigo. Porqué no hacerlo sin tanta complicación?

Comment: Eso se interpreta de forma superficial. Pero, puedes que el OP **quiera realizar algún proceso** antes de ejecutar los scripts; por ende, el uso de `defer` no serviría de mucho.

Comment: Con la edición se entiende mejor lo que tratas de decir. Saludos.